# Utility to show live keyboard and mouse status for teaching and screencasts

Tags: windows, presentations

looking for a **windows** alternative to Keyboard Status Monitor (key-mon).
currently for linux only. i do not need to record the screen just pop up the key pressed.
i can probebly do it in auto-it but would like to know if there is something available.

http://code.google.com/p/key-mon/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](http://dan.hersam.com/2009/05/01/how-to-display-keystrokes-for-screencasts-on-windows/) website has three programs for Windows computers.

[Blender 3D](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.5/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Screencast_Key_Status_Tool) has a script to display keyboard and mouse.

-ssmeier

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [QiPress](http://aalapshah.in/project/qipress) is currently the most up to date one.